# Wearable Data integration - MiBand 2

Tags: android, synchronization, wear-os

Like to build a app which visualise the data from MiBand-2 , Is it possible to sync data from Mi Band-2 device to app we build. If yes where to find the SDK or instructions for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [list of android wear device](https://www.android.com/wear/), you will not find here the MiBand-2. What can I give you is this two github that uses/supported MiBand device. So try to check it if it can help you. Also, check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html) of Android Wear Device to know how to build apps for Wearables.

- [Github 1](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge)
- [Github 2](https://github.com/betomaluje/Mi-Band)